# How to set up proxy for SSH connection to GitHub on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04)?

Tags: git, ssh, proxy

I am trying to set up a proxy for SSH connection to GitHub on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) using my own proxy server at 172.26.160.1:7890. I have tried to add the following to `~/.ssh/config` for GitHub SSH:

```
Host github.com
    ProxyCommand nc -X 5 -x 172.26.160.1:7890 %h %p
```

However, after waiting for a while, I received the following error message:

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I have also tried to install ncat and change the `ProxyCommand` to the following:

```
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/ncat --proxy 172.26.160.1:7890 --proxy-type http %h %p
```

But I still received the same error message.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to set up a proxy for SSH connection to GitHub on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04)? Thank you very much!

When I set `ProxyCommand nc -X 5 -x 172.26.160.1:7890 %h %p`,

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com

OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ming/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/ming/.ssh/config line 20: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec nc -X 5 -x 172.26.160.1:7890 github.com 22
debug1: identity file /home/ming/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/ming/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
# long time pass ...
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

But when I unset `ProxyCommand` in ~/.ssh/config, `ssh -vT git@github.com` works well.